# Can I modify the Field Label name once the custom field has existing records?

Tags: custom-fields, database

Can I modify the Custom Field Label Name once the custom field has existing records?

Will it cause any errors in the database, or are there any concerns that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a problem to change the label in the UI.

(But avoid changing the `name` field directly in mysql/phpmyadmin. It is different from `label` in the database and may cause problems depending on what created the field.)